# Как разобраться в структуре jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Привет. Хочу изучить исходники jQuery. Основная цель - брать куски и вставлять в свой код.
Может подскажете, как разобраться в этом коде. Может, есть статья по пояснению каждого участка кода в библиотеке. Исходники скачал в https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src.

Comment: А с какой целью нужно
>брать куски и вставлять в свой код
?

Comment: Ну, допустим, может можно брать тот же самый (document).ready без остальной части библиотеки.

Comment: zloctb, а смысл Вам такой кусок кода вставлять? После (document).ready должен идти jQuery код, если я не ошибаюсь...

Comment: @ka5itoshka **Любой javascript код**, написанный внутри блока `$(document).ready()`, будет выполнен только один раз, после того, как страница окажется в состоянии ready.

---------------------------------

Так что не обязатеьно jQuery должен идти после (document).ready()!

Comment: >Основная цель - брать куски и вставлять в свой код

это попытка сделать видимость отсутсвия использования jQuery - не очень хорошая идея

Comment: Есть версия [jQuery с комментариями][1] от самого Резига. Если что-то не понятно, надо включить логику.

[1]: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто начни читать - с функции $ - как она работает, что возвращает, потом как работают сложные селекторы, события.

ИМХО лучше использовать jQuery, а не куски его текста - меньше говнокода получится. Или какая мотивация не использовать jQuery?